# How to make spring load JPA classes from multiple paths?

Tags: spring, jpa

So I have a spring application divided into several modules, each in a separate project. 
Each module has its own JPA entities and I'm using Spring ORM for configuration:

```
<beans ...>

<context:component-scan
    base-package="org.myapp.module1.persistence" />

<context:component-scan
    base-package="org.myapp.module2.persistence" />

...

<context:annotation-config />

<tx:annotation-driven />

...

</beans>
```

And the persistence.xml file looks like this:

```
<persistence ...>

<persistence-unit name="myunit" />

</persistence>
```

My problem is that when Spring context initializes it will only look for the @Entity classes on the same path of the persistence.xml file, and will ignore the other projects classpaths.

I tried to have multiple persistence.xml, each one in the same path as the @Entity classes, but in this case once Spring finds the first persistence.xml it stops loading and will not find any @Entity classes on other paths.

How can I make Spring look at everything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you want to build a single persistence unit from multiple `persistence.xml` files you could use the [MergingPersistenceUnitManager](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/support/MergingPersistenceUnitManager.java) available in Spring Data JPA. Be sure to give all of your persistence units the same name. Of course, you have to use the wildcarded import for the `persistence.xml`: `classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml`

Regards,
Ollie

Comment: the link is broken. Updated link:
http://redmine.synyx.org/projects/minos/repository/changes/trunk/modules/core/src/main/java/org/synyx/minos/support/jpa/MergingPersistenceUnitManager.java

Answer (score 1):

maybe [spring jpa - multiple persistence units](http://static.springframework.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-multiple-pu) does help